# Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS won't let me enter password

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I have a old MESH PC with a 160GB SATA harddrive, 2.5GB of ram and a 1.5Ghz proccesor (AMD Sempron) I logged into Ubuntu today and it wouldn't let me type in the password, let me click, or just about anything!

I have installed ZSNES (SNES emulator), PCSX (Playstation emulator) Dosemu (DOS emulator), Chromium (web browser) and Virtualbox (runs a guest PC on a normal PC)

Comment: What do you mean by ' it wouldn't let me'? In case you've meant typing passwords in a terminal window, just type it and hit Enter. There won't be any visual feedback, which is normal.

Answer (score 2):

if you are talking about logging in to the graphical interface then you might want to try

<kbd>cnt</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

that should bring you to a terminal window. Then you can issue the command:

> sudo service lightdm restart

This should restart the graphic interface and allow you to login.

If that does not work then the system may have hung. If that is the case you can try turning off via the power button (press and hold until it turns off if needed). Then try to power it up again. If you have the same issue on restart let us know if any patches or upgrades were done recently.